# “React” undefined for React Router with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is my React Router setup that I want to run through Typescript. It works without Typescript, but not with it. I get an runtime error in my browser console. Transpilation works fine though. It doesn’t make a difference if I include a “react.js” and “react-dom.js” seperately or a giant “bundle.js” with everything included. What am I doing wrong?

Error:

```
Router.js:91 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined
// For context, the line says: React.Component
at Object../node_modules/react-router/es/Router.js (Router.js:91)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Object../node_modules/react-router-dom/es/Router.js (Router.js:2)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Object../node_modules/react-router-dom/es/BrowserRouter.js (BrowserRouter.js:11)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Object../node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js (index.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Object../src/index.tsx (index.tsx:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

Code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch }  from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/test/" render={() => (
            <div>
                Test.
            </div>
        )} />
        <Route exact={true} path="/" render={() => (
            <div>
                Root page.
            </div>
        )} />
        </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.

The solution was to add `"esModuleInterop": true` to my `tsconfig.json`.

Additionally, `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` allowed me to write `import React from "react";` instead of `import * as React from "react";`.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The way you import React is the problem. You should replace all your importing statements with something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: I had this before. Now I get these kinds of errors: `ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:1:8 
        TS1192: Module '"/%path%/node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no default 
export. `

Comment: Okay. I managed to to that via `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in my `tsconfig.json` but now I am getting the same error from my initial post.